# I came to realise... the meaning of "come +infinitive"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

When someone says "I came to realise...", I know it can mean he realised it gradually.

Can it mean one day he suddenly realised something? For example,

> One week later, I came to realise that I missed my appointment.

If this is wrong, can I ask how to express the meaning of I realised something very late?

For example, normally people realise they missed an appointment on the day or next day, but I realised it one week later.

Comment: Your dictionary provides many definitions and usages of the verb _come._ Which one do you think applies to the usage in _"come to realize"_? For instance, the [**Collins Dictionary**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come), which I think is not censored by any government, has as definition number 14: _"(tr; takes an infinitive) to be given awareness ⇒ I came to realize its enormous value."_  What dictionary do you use?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think what you are saying is that it can mean suddenly realised something but to be honest, I won't know that by reading 14.

Comment: "I came to realise/understand/see...." implies over a period of time but doesn't specify what period. It would more commonly be used after: "Over/during the next few days/weeks/months, I came to....." than "one week/month later".

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you for letting me know. May I ask what phrase can I use to express 'suddenly realised something after a period of time such as a week/month later'?

Comment: Well, we *should* close questions as off-topic if they're entirely answerable by a dictionary.  The definition P. E. Dant quoted, however, doesn't really answer the question, so that doesn't seem to apply here.  At any rate, if we're going to recommend dictionaries to learners, we should probably link to learner's dictionaries when we can, rather than to dictionaries written for native speakers, like Collins Dictionary.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48685/discussion-on-question-by-emmaxl-i-came-to-realise-the-meaning-of-come-infi).

Comment: @EmmaXL You've said it yourself: "A week/month later I suddenly realised..." or "it came to me" or "it struck me".

Comment: @P.E.Dant This comment is not a good comment for this site given the question concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To express realizing *something* much later on

> *Only after some time* was I able to realize...
>   I realized *much later* that...

the amount of time is usually a modifying phrase.  It is implied that the realization came somewhat suddenly since if the realization was progressive one might use

> *Over a period of time*, I was able to realize...

For something really sudden

> only later did it **hit** me
>   *some time afterwards I suddenly realized*